# Xcode 9 iOS 11 simulators Touch ID not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9

I have turned on `Hardware > Touch ID > Enrolled`, but [canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics:error:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514149-canevaluatepolicy) is still returning `false`.

This issue only occurs on the iOS 11 simulators in Xcode 9 and works fine if I run an iOS 10 simulator from Xcode 9.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or why this might be happening?

Comment: According to the Xcode 9 beta 5 release notes, this has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue as of Xcode 9 beta 4. See page 19 of the [release notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_4/Xcode_9_beta_4_Release_Notes.pdf).

Comment: According to the Xcode 9 beta 5 release notes, this has been fixed.